# Save output from Lilypad Arduino

Tags: serial-port, arduino

When we call the `Serial.println` function in the sketch it print the output to Serial channel.

Is there a way to get the output later when the LilyPad is connected to a PC and save it to disk in PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an SD Card and save data to that.  Although it would be much simpler to use the onboard 512 bytes of EEPROM.

[**EEPROM Write Tutorial**](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMWrite)

```
EEPROM.write(addr, val);
```

[**EEPROM Read Tutorial**](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMRead)

```
value = EEPROM.read(address);
```

Depending on your IO pins available, you could also add some extra EEPROM.

[**I2CEEPROM**](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/I2CEEPROM)